# Hadoop configuration in sparkR

Tags: r, hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-spark, sparkr

I have some problems to configure hadoop with sparkR in order to read/write data from amazon S3.
For example these are the commands that works in pyspark (to solve the same issue):

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "myaccesskey")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "mysecretaccesskey")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.endpoint", "myentrypoint")
```

Could anybody help me to work this out?

Comment: `awsSecretAccessKey`  and  `awsAccessKeyId` can be set using environmental variables. See: [Running Spark on EC2](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution closer to what you are doing with PySpark can be achieved by using `callJMethod` (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/R/pkg/R/backend.R#L31)

```
> hConf = SparkR:::callJMethod(sc, "hadoopConfiguration")
> SparkR:::callJMethod(hConf, "set", "a", "b")
NULL
> SparkR:::callJMethod(hConf, "get", "a")
[1] "b"
```

**UPDATE:**

`hadoopConfiguration` didn't work for me: `conf` worked though - presumably it's changed at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You can set

```
<property>
    <name>fs.s3n.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem</value>
</property>
```

in your core-site.xml (yarn configuration)